# How do I forward touch events to a view behind a uicollectionview?

Tags: uicollectionview

I have a uicollectionviewcontroller which I use to create a small toolbar at the bottom of the screen.  I add the view of the uicollectionviewcontroller to another viewcontroller's view.  My problem is that it won't forward touch events to a view underneath it.  I did move it to the bottom and that worked for a while but now I need to use 2 uicollection views.

How am I supposed to forward touch events to views beneath a uicollectionviewcontroller's view?

Answer (score 2):

In case the question is still relevant, the following can be used to achieve touch forwarding.

1. Subclass UICollectionView
2. Overwrite - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

   ```
   -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
       [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
       [self.yourCustomDelegate forwardTouches:touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event];
   }
   ```

   That is how UICollectionView can keep its ability to respond to user interaction, and the same time forward received touches.

Answer (score 0):

As i think you can add your toolbar as footer of UICollectionView and it will work

have a look into this link [How to Add Header and Footer View in UICollectionView](http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/)